# JUnit testing deletion of a text file using a testing text file

Tags: java, file, testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to write a JUnit test for a java code that with three methods.

**FileDeletion.java**:

```
public static void fileDeletion(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.delete();
}
```

I looked online on how to test this, but it came up with how to make a temporary file in JUnit which is "guaranteed to be deleted after the test finishes".
See: https://howtodoinjava.com/junit/junit-creating-temporary-filefolder-using-temporaryfolder-rule/

**How do I make a file which can be created and then subsequently deleted in a JUnit Test?**
Any help would go a long way, many thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need to create a new file in the unit test?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using JUnit's TemporaryFolder rule to help you set up the file and directory structure you need for your test which is cleaned up after your test.

```
public class DeleteFileTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final File file = folder.newFile("myfile1.txt");
        file.delete();
        
        //Assert
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but wouldn't the file get deleted regardless of the test if the folder is temporary?

Comment: Yes, the file and the temporary folder gets deleted **after** the test. But in the test method you can unit test the behaviour of the file. If you delete the file you can assert if the file exists in the temporary folder for example.

Comment: to implement into the method I have currently this:

Comment: `public class ClearFileMethodTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final File file = folder.newFile("myfile1.txt");
        isFileCleared = FileManagement.clearFile("myfile1.txt");
      //assertTrue - jUnit boolean condition which checks whether the expected value is true or not.
        assertTrue(file.isEmpty());
    }

}` but the `isEmpty` assertion seems incorrect, is it as i am dealing with file path not file name?

Comment: What are you trying to test? If your FileManagement class clears the file?

Comment: You can try it with `assertTrue(file.length() == 0)` if you want to check for empty file.